# git-ignore doesn't ignoring node_modules

Tags: reactjs, git, node-modules, gitignore

[image: My folder structure]

I include node_modules in gitignore but still github desktop suggest changes to push.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `node_modules/` to your `.gitignore` file at a moment where your existing directory was already tracked in git, you need one extra step to make git "forget" about this directory:

```
git rm --cached -r node_modules/
git commit
```

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced same issue some time back. In my case after, updated the .gitignore after making commit into repo. So below are the steps i have followed up to resolve same -

Step 1 - Commit all your changes into repo.

Step 2 - Refresh your git repository index by running below command.
**git rm -r --cached**
Step 3 - Add everything back using **git add .**

Step 4 - Finally commit your changes like **git commit -m ".gitignore fix"**

Now you won't see node_modules coming into changes.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have already added some files from node_modules folder in your repo (otherwise the color of the node_modules folder would be green instead of brown)

You can look which files are tracked in your repo using this

```bash
git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD
```

And you can remove a directory from git using this

```bash
git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

And don't forget to commit changes after that.

```bash
git add .
git commit -m "remove node_modules folder"
```